# Upload files with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to upload file from frontend

*servece.ts*

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

formdata.append('file', file);

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/upload', formdata, {
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'text'
});

return this.http.request(req);
}
```

I created a webservice with flask to save files, which strongly follows the officially flask example:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/upload/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'pcap'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
print(request.files)
# check if the post request has the file part
if 'file' not in request.files:
    print('no file in request')
    return""
file = request.files['file']
if file.filename == '':
    print('no selected file')
    return""
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    print("hello")
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return ""
print("end")
return""
```

Result - no exceptions and no file upload
When trying to handle the upload via Angular HttpClient, flask detects no file in request

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2018 13:46:25] "OPTIONS /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

*file-upload.html*

```
    <div *ngIf="currentFileUpload" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" attr.aria-valuenow="{{progress.percentage}}"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{width:progress.percentage+'%'}">
    {{progress.percentage}}%</div>
</div>

<label class="btn btn-default">
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" accept=".pcap">
</label>

<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

*upload.component.ts*

```
upload() {
    this.progress.percentage = 0;

    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.uploadService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
      }
    });

    this.selectedFiles = undefined;
  }
```

What is the problem i'm no e?

Comment: Are you getting `cors` error in console?

Comment: Only this
      Failed to load http://localhost:8080/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
core.js:1449 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

Comment: Yep . You'll have to enable `cors` from your flask to  do that . Unless you're requesting from same origin ( in your  case localhost:8080) . You'll need to configure [cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you, problem is solved